# How to change frames in sprite sheet when different keys are pressed. XNA

Tags: c#, animation, xna, sprite-sheet

What I'm trying to achieve is a realistic walk animation where a character is at a static frame and then when <kbd>Right</kbd> is pressed it will load the character animation I created.

I've tried messing around with this and so far all I've gotten are errors.
Here is my code:
Sprite

```cs
public class Sprite
{
    public static SpriteManager spriteManager;
    private int sectorNumber;
    private string name;
    private TextureData textureData;
    private SpritePresentationInfo spritePresentationInfo;
    private SpritePositionInfo spritePositionInfo;


    public Sprite(string name, TextureData textureData, 
                SpritePresentationInfo spritePresentationInfo,
                    SpritePositionInfo spritePositionInfo)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.textureData = textureData;
        this.spritePresentationInfo = spritePresentationInfo;
        this.spritePositionInfo = spritePositionInfo;

        //make sure we set first time around
        this.sectorNumber = Collision.getSectorNumber(this.POSITIONINFO.BOUNDS);

    }
```

AnimatedSprite

```cs
public class AnimatedSprite : Sprite
{
    protected AnimatedTextureData animatedTextureData;
    protected int frameRate, startFrame, currentFrame = 0;
    protected bool bRepeatAnimation, bPause;
    protected double timeSinceLastFrameInMs, timeBetweenFrameInMs;

    #region PROPERTIES
    #endregion

    public AnimatedSprite(string name, AnimatedTextureData animatedTextureData,
                SpritePresentationInfo spritePresentationInfo,
                    SpritePositionInfo spritePositionInfo,
                        int frameRate, int startFrame, bool bRepeatAnimation)
        : base(name, animatedTextureData, spritePresentationInfo, spritePositionInfo)
    {
        this.animatedTextureData = animatedTextureData;// (AnimatedTextureData)animatedTextureData.Clone();

        this.frameRate = frameRate;
        timeBetweenFrameInMs = 1000.0 / frameRate; //time between each frame if they play at frameRate per second (e.g. 24fps gives timeBetweenFrameInMs = 1000ms/24 per second)
        timeSinceLastFrameInMs = timeBetweenFrameInMs; //means no initial delay in animation
        this.startFrame = startFrame;
        currentFrame = startFrame;
        this.bRepeatAnimation = bRepeatAnimation;
    }
```

PlayerSprite.

```cs
public class PlayerSprite : Sprite
{
    protected Keys leftKey, rightKey;
    //private float moveIncrement = 0.5f;
    private int move;


    public PlayerSprite(string name, AnimatedTextureData textureData, SpritePresentationInfo spritePresentationInfo,
       SpritePositionInfo spritePositionInfo, Keys leftKey, Keys rightKey)
        : base(name, textureData, spritePresentationInfo, spritePositionInfo)
    {
        this.leftKey = leftKey; 
        this.rightKey = rightKey;
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Use this if we do not want to use the parents
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        handleInput(gameTime);

        base.Update(gameTime);
    }
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    //  Use this if we do not want to use the parents
    //-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected override void handleInput(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        this.move = (int)(GameData.PLAYER_MOVE_INCREMENT * gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds);
        if (SpriteManager.GAME.KEYBOARDMANAGER.isKeyDown(leftKey))
            MoveBy(-move, 0);
       //This is where i want to initialize the walk animation.
        if (SpriteManager.GAME.KEYBOARDMANAGER.isKeyDown(rightKey))
            MoveBy(move, 0);
    }
```

Main.  I have it working and animating without a key press in main.

```cs
textureManager.Add("PlayerAnimation", "Assets\\Animations\\Characters\\Player\\Player_AnimationFinal", 8, 75,200);
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//Player Animation
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

AnimatedTextureData playerAnimatedTextureData = (AnimatedTextureData)textureManager.Get("PlayerAnimation");
SpritePresentationInfo playerAnimatedPresentationInfo = new SpritePresentationInfo(playerAnimatedTextureData.FULLSOURCERECTANGLE, 0);
SpritePositionInfo playerAnimatedPositionInfo = new SpritePositionInfo(new Vector2(100, 700), playerAnimatedTextureData.Width(), playerAnimatedTextureData.Height(), 0, 2, playerAnimatedTextureData.CENTREORIGIN);
spriteManager.Add(new AnimatedSprite("PlayerAnimation", playerAnimatedTextureData, playerAnimatedPresentationInfo, playerAnimatedPositionInfo,10, 0, true));

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: No one is going to read all of that, narrow down your question to a specific issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way is to use sprite sheet for animations. one single image that contain all sprites. And then simple by changing `currentFrame` (from 0 to 7) you show only this part of image.

```
sourceRect = new Rectangle(currentFrame * spriteWidth, 0, spriteWidth, spriteHeight)
```

and draw like this

```
SpriteBatch.Draw (Texture2D, Position, sourceRect, Color)
```

example of sprite sheet image
[image]